# The status of the internet

Tags: internet

What are the best services to let you know the state of every internet service provider.

I recall there were companies that you could subscribe to that would let you see a graphical map of the status of were there are outages or problems throughout the web.

What are the best services for this? Paid or non-paid, whatever does the job is what I am looking for.

Comment: When you say "every" do you mean globally or just some particular part of the planet?

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.internettrafficreport.com/
- http://www.internettrafficreport.com/details.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, although I believe it's focused on North America:

http://www.internetpulse.net/